# Two ways to describe image of a filter under a function

Tags: set-theory, filters

Let $f$ be a function from a set $A$ to a set $B$.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a filter on $A$. (Note that I do *not* require that all filters are proper.)

It is easy to verify that $\{Y\in\mathscr{P}B \mid f^{-1}[Y]\in\mathcal{A} \}$ is a filter:

That it's an upper set is quite obvious. Let $Y_1,Y_2\in\{Y\in\mathscr{P}B \mid f^{-1}[Y]\in\mathcal{A} \}$. Then $f^{-1}[Y_1]\in\mathcal{A}$ and $f^{-1}[Y_2]\in\mathcal{A}$ and thus $f^{-1}[Y_1]\cap f^{-1}[Y_2]=f^{-1}[Y_1\cap Y_2]\in\{Y\in\mathscr{P}B \mid f^{-1}[Y]\in\mathcal{A} \}$ because $f$ is monovalued.

Please help to find the shortest proof that the filter $\{Y\in\mathscr{P}B \mid f^{-1}[Y]\in\mathcal{A} \}$ is equal to the filter generated by filter base $\{ f[A] \mid A\in\mathcal{A} \}$.

Comment: I wonder that Google for `("filter image" | "image of filter") function set "filter base"` does not find relevant enough results

Comment: Hm, I spent around ten minus trying to prove this, yet without success. I expected it to be easier. Any proof (not only the shortest one) would be helpful

Comment: "minus" -> "minutes" in my previous comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call $\mathcal{B}= \{ Y \subseteq B : f^{-1}(Y) \in \mathcal{A} \}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ the filter generated by $\{ f(A) :A\in \mathcal{A} \}$.

For all $A \in \mathcal{A}$, you have $f^{-1}(f(A)) \supseteq A$, so $f^{-1}(f(A)) \in \mathcal{A}$. This proves that $f(A) \in \mathcal{B}$. In particular $\mathcal{F} \subseteq\mathcal{B}$.

On the other hand, for all $Y \in \mathcal{B}$ you have $f(f^{-1}(Y)) \subseteq Y$. Since $f^{-1}(Y) \in \mathcal{A}$, you have that $Y$ is a supset of some set of the form $f(A)$: so $Y \in \mathcal{F}$. THis shows the other inclusion
$\mathcal{F} \supseteq\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: +1: Note that in the first line it should say $\{f(A) \colon A \in \mathcal{A}\}$.

Comment: +1 + typo corrected