# Image of a filter

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\prod_{i\in I} X_{i}$ be product topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a filter on $X$. As I read in some texts, the image Filter of $\mathcal{F}$ under any projection $\pi_{i}$ is the family of sets $\pi_{i}(\mathcal{F})=\{A\subset X_{i} : \exists U\in\mathcal{F} \text{ such that} \pi_{i}(U)\subset A\}$. And this makes me confused. How do we know that there is such an $U\in\mathcal{F}$? Is this a general definition of “image filter”? Because as I know, the image of the filter $\mathcal{F}$ under a mapping $f:X\to Y$ is $f(\mathcal{F})=\{U\subset Y : f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{F}\}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two ways to describe image of a filter under a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467769/two-ways-to-describe-image-of-a-filter-under-a-function)

Comment: I am asking just, how do we know there is such $U$, @AnneBauval

Comment: I do not understand that part of your question. We "know" nothing about general subsets $A$ of $X_i,$ and we *define* $\pi_i(\mathcal F)$ as the set of those $A$ for which "there is such $U$". The more interesting part of your question is answered in the duplicate, isn't it?

Comment: I mean, the image filter under $f$ is $f(\mathcal{F})=\{U\subset Y: f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{F}\}$. So according to this definition, I think $\pi_{i}(\mathcal{F})=\{A\subset X_{i}: \pi_{i}^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{F}\}. So is this $pi_{i}(\mathcal{F})$ and $\pi_{i}(\mathcal{F})=\{A\subset X_{i} : \exists U\in\mathcal{F} \text{ such that} \pi_{i}(U)\subset A\}$ the same?

Comment: This is what is proved in the duplicate. Remember that the "filter generated by a filter base $\mathcal B$" is the set of $A$'s s.t. $\exists B\in\mathcal B, B\subset A.$

Comment: Aww, I understood it very well right now. The $\pi_{i}(\mathcal{F})$ is a filter base, that is why it coincides with the duplicate. Thank you very much. @AnneBauval

Comment: Not exactly. Of course every filter is a filter base of itself, but the filter base used here to *generate* the filter $\pi_i(\mathcal F)$ is $\mathcal B:=\{\pi_i(U)\mid U\in\mathcal F\}.$ In this context, this base cannot be denoted by $\pi_i(\mathcal F)$: there would be a conflict of notation.

Comment: I totally understand it right now. It is my mistyping I think. Now everything is very well settled for me, thank you very much @AnneBauval